# Как выбрать кнопку ,в ячейке таблицы с опреденным названием

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

Подскажите пожалуйста . Есть таблица, в которой есть ячейка(строка) разбитая на столбцы. 
Надо основываясь на названии этой строки провести взаимодействия с кнопками, относящимися к этой строке.
Понимаю что довольно низкоквалифицированный вопрос, но пытаюсь освоить азы автоматизации сам, и иногда вещи ставят в тупик, не всегда получается найти ответ в гугле. Использую в работе `Java` , `Selenium` + `selenide` + `junit 5`.

[image: Данные]

Answer (score 0):

Можно испьльзовать метод $(byText("text") если текст данной ячейки уникален или же использовать $(By.linkText("text") если это тег